# Popup window on hover using jquery

Tags: jquery, popup

OK, getting extremely frustrated here. I know what I want to do isn't complicated, but I can't find a nice simple answer.

I want a popup window when I hover over image. The popup should be to the right of the image.
That's it.

This is used to show an image on where to find the CVV# of a credit card if they don't already know.

I keep finding all these samples that combine what I'm looking for with 18 other things all at the same time, making it impossible for a beginner to jquery to sort it out.

I don't want to combine it into a menu system, I don't want apply this code to every single copy of a certain tag, nor do I want it to sing and dance.

I do believe that the popup has to be in it's own DIV because the image that triggering the hover is inside a table that I don't want to alter.

I'm about 2 inches (5 cm for my overseas friends) away from just saying fu-- it and making it popup in a new browser window. The reason I'm doing this way is because I think it's a better style, and because I want to learn jquery.

If someone can please explain it to me in very simple terms, I would very much appreciate it. If you want to add some other features that you think would be helpful like rounded corners, that's OK as long as I can easily tell what code goes with what.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Unless you absolutely have to, don't use popups. You could easily just display a new `<div>` besides the field that perhaps has an image that tells the user where to find the CVV number.

Comment: If you thought about your problem and tried to understand the principles of the language instead of cargo-cultist coding then you would have seen to break it down into parts, such as: I need to do something on hover of _x_; I then need to find the invisible element _y_ I've previously hidden and show it; when no longer hovering ...etc. But of course, those damned complex tutorials!

Comment: @GrantThomas, if you have a whole lot going on, and you're new to it, it's not always a simple matter of dissecting the code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Something like this maybe :

```
$('.popover').on({
    mousemove: function(e) {
        $(this).next('img').css({
            top: e.pageY - 260,
            left: e.pageX + 10
        });
    },
    mouseenter: function() {
        var big = $('<img />', {'class': 'big_img', src: this.src});
        $(this).after(big);
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        $('.big_img').remove();
    }
});
```

[**DEMONSTRATION**](http://jsfiddle.net/9B28P/)

Or with no javascript, just CSS : [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/9B28P/1/)

Comment: OK, I'm very close. 2 problems I'm running into. First, I'm using different images. A little question mark and the diagram. I changed this.src to the name of the source and that worked, but I don't know if that's the proper way. Second, is the position of the smaller img. You have it at 200,200, but I changed it to 0,0. Everything works fine in fiddle, but not on my page. Here's my code: http://jsfiddle.net/gEt6U/

Comment: Well, I never did solve it. Turns out a lot of what I was trying did in fact work when done on another page, but were blocked for some reason on the page I was working on. That page is kinda complicated with a bunch of DIVs, so maybe that was interfering with it. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Woah, chill man.

Here's a technique I'll suggest using.

Appending a `<div>` to the end of the `<body>` as the container for your popup. http://jqapi.com/#p=append

Next you need to know the positions of where you want to set it, relative to document. You can get the offset of the hovered element using jQuery's offset http://jqapi.com/#p=offset

Then you'll calculate the width of the hovered element, then set the popup beside it using CSS, `position: absolute`. To set a positioning context, it's best practice to set `position:relative` to the parent element as well, in this case it is `<body>`.
You'll need to set the CSS attribute of `top` and `left` for your popup container.

Suggestion for the hover mechanics http://jqapi.com/#p=hover

You'll need to create a hover handler in the form of a function. One function for "hover in" and an optional one for "hover out"

There's a bootstrap implementation of popover http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#popovers
Maybe looking into the source might enlighten you.

Hope that helps.

Comment: A little more than what I wanted on this question, but looks like a good tutorial for me to come back to when I have a little more time. Thanks. P.S. I'm much more chill today. :-)